# use of Jquery enabled site

Tags: jquery

I was wondering whether clients have to use any plugin for using a site where jquery has been used. I am developing a site having jquery, when mit is used by our clients do they have to download or install some plugin on their client machine so that site which i am developing is working properly ?

Thanks

Comment: No. As long as you include jquery in your page, it's all needed to run the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a JavaScript framework and it's written in JS. Everything you need is just include it into your webpage and it will work as other JS files work.

Read the article to get around [how JS frameworks work](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/external.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is "just" a bunch of JavaScript code which works as any other JavaScript code. So no, your users won't have to install anything. You just include jQuery as any other JS file in your HTML and that's it.